# How to increase hover area for Line D3v4

Tags: d3.js

I have a hover effect on the line but the line is thin, so I have to increase the hover area so that user can hover easily.

Any one has the same issue?

Comment: increase the `stroke-width`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Increasing stroke-width, increase the height of the line. Line should be thin but hover area should be larger than that so that user can easily access the line.

Answer (score 4):

If you set color to `"transparent"`, the path will react to mouse events, but will not be visible.

For example, suppose you have a `<line>` (or `<path>`, it doesn't matter):

```
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 10).attr('y1', 10)
  .attr('x2', 50).attr('y2', 50)
  .attr('stroke', 'black').attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .on('click', () => console.log('click!'));
```

I suggest to add second `<line>` with greater `stroke-width` and `stroke="transparent"`. You can use `.clone` method for this:

```
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 10).attr('y1', 10)
  .attr('x2', 50).attr('y2', 50)
  .attr('stroke', 'black').attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .clone()
    .attr('stroke', 'transparent').attr('stroke-width', 10)    
    .on('click', () => console.log('click!'));
```